# What to return from apache beam pcollection to write to bigquery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am reading beam documentation and some of stackoverflow questions/[answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183876/how-do-you-access-the-message-id-from-google-pub-sub-using-apache-beam/57187385) in order to understand how would i write a pubsub message to bigquery. As of now, I have working example of getting `protobuf` messages and able to `decode` them. the code looks like this

```
(p
 | 'ReadData' >> apache_beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input_topic, with_attributes=True)
 | 'ParsePubsubMessage' >> apache_beam.Map(parse_pubsubmessage)
 )
```

Eventually, what i want to do is write decoded pub-sub message to bigquery. all attribtues (and decoded byte data) will have one-to-one column mapping.

So what is confusing me is what should my `parse_pubsubmessage` return. As of now, It is returning a custom class which has all fields i.e.,

```
class DecodedPubsubMessage:
    def __init__(self, attr, event):
        self.attribute_one = attr['attribute_one']
        self.attribute_two = attr['attribute_two']

        self.order_id = event.order.order_id
        self.sku = event.item.item_id
        self.triggered_at = event.timestamp
        self.status = event.order.status
```

Is this correct approach to do this dataflow? What i was thinking that i will use this returned value to write to bigquery but due to advance python feature, i am unable to understand how to. Here is a reference [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854167/dataflow-streaming-using-python-sdk-transform-for-pubsub-messages-to-bigquery-o) that i was looking at. From this example, I am not sure how would i do the `lambda` map on my returned object to write to bigquery.

Comment: Do you want to save all the attributes of this class as table fields?

Answer (score 0):

Your class must inherit from DoFn and overload the "process" method and not do the transformation on **init**

and after the transformation you can use the "return [obj]" or "yield obj" to return the desired output PCollection